# Is $G/ \langle a^{30} \rangle \cong \langle a^{60} \rangle$ if order of $G = \langle a \rangle$ is $1800$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is $G/ \langle a^{30} \rangle \cong \langle a^{60} \rangle$ if order of $G = \langle a \rangle$ is $1800$?

I am not sure about this,  $G/ \langle a^{30} \rangle  = \{g \langle a^{30} \rangle | g \in G \}$, and it seems like these two groups have exact number of elements?

Comment: What do you know about quotients of cyclic groups?

Comment: They are again cyclic?

Comment: Yes.  You should add some of this as context/effort in your post to prevent closure.

Comment: But I am confused, if they have the same number of elements, and they are finite, how they can't be an isomorphism between them?

Comment: It matters that there is a **unique** cyclic group of any given order up to iso.

Comment: You have groups generated by a single element, i.e. cyclic groups. They are also abelian, so $G=\langle a \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_{30}\times \mathbb{Z}_{60}.$ Now count the elements. Alternatively, use Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @MariusS.L. $\Bbb Z_{60}×\Bbb Z_{30}$ isn't cyclic.

Comment: @eggnog So they are isomorphic?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: That is what I thought, but my teacher said that they are not, so I was pretty confused...

Comment: He must have erred.

Comment: @MariusS.L. Only when $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime is $\Bbb Z_r\times \Bbb Z_s$ cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

The order of $a^{30}$ is $\dfrac {1800}{(1800,30)}=60$.

Also,  any quotient (homomorphic image) of a cyclic group is cyclic.   So $G/\langle a^{30}\rangle \cong C_{30}$.

Finally $\lvert a^{60}\rvert =\dfrac {1800}{(1800,60)}=30$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small but crucial mistake here. Elements of $G/H$ are not elements of $G$; they are cosets $gH$, with $g\in G$.

Let $G=\langle a\rangle$ and $H=\langle a^{30}\rangle$. We agree that $|H|=60$, and so $|G/H| = 30$. $G/H$ is generated by $a^{1800/30}H = a^{60}H$. That is, $G/H = \langle a^{60}H\rangle$.

Comment: All it claims is that they're isomorphic.

Comment: @eggnog Point taken. After 40 years of teaching university mathematics, I am used to seeing various versions of misunderstanding of quotients. You’re right that the OP wrote $\cong$ and not $=$. So it is correct. But I would still try to break bad habits …

Comment: @TedShifrin What bad habits? Saying that two things that are isomorphic are in fact isomorphic?

Comment: @Arthur No, writing elements of $G$ for elements of $G/H$. But I suspect you understood that just fine.

Comment: @TedShifrin When did they do that?